# Scala generic Function vs Generic Method

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

So far i was under the impression that the only way to define Generic function in scala, was using Method e.g.

```
def myToString[A](value: A) = {println(value)}
```

However i figured the following way:

```
val myToStringFun: (T forSome {type T}) => Unit = value => println(value)
```

Is there something that i am not seeing or is that the pattern to write generic function in Scala without resorting to method ?

I never seen that pattern before, and only came up with it, based my learning around Higher-Kinded Type and the notion of existential ...

Please share your thoughts or wisdom on this....

EDIT1:

If the above is correct, why is it that this pattern is not used and people systematically resort to Method for generic function. Is it just a ease of notation

EDIT2:

If a function `(T forSome {type T}) => Unit` <=> `Any => Unit`

It seems however that

```
val mySeqToString: (Seq[T] forSome {type T}) => String = {
    case head +: tail => s"$head +: " + seqToString(tail)
    case Nil => "Nil"
}
```

is equivalent to

```
def seqToString[T](seq: Seq[T]): String = seq match {
    case head +: tail => s"$head +: " + seqToString(tail)
    case Nil => "Nil"
}
```

correct ?

Comment: That is not a generic that is an existential and at that point that is just fancy and confusing syntax for **Any**. That `T` is not usable in any sense, try to write a generic identity function with that or a function that accepts a `T` and a **List** of `Ts` and returns a **Boleean** that checks if the list contained that element.

Comment: Interesting, so writing `def method[F[_]](e: F[T] forSome {type T}): String = ???` is like saying `e: F[Any]` ???

Comment: Existentials are a bit different than **Any**, especially because they behave differently given the variance of the object. But, I personally have never found them useful _(also, they always surprise me, so it is fair to say I really do not understand them)_.

Comment: existential type will also be removed in Scala 3

Comment: @texasbruce Not all of them.

Comment: Scala 3 will have proper [polymorphic functions](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672)

Answer (score 4):

Type `A` in your function is a standard generic type. You can do many things with it, such as demand a typeclass instance:

```
import cats.implicits._
def myToString[A: cats.Show](value: A) = { println(value.show) }
```

On the other hand, type `(T forSome {type T})` is an [existential type](https://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/). You might recognize it by its more popular shorthand notation, `_` (e.g. `List[_]`). Not much you can do with that one. If you check the type of `value` in

```
val myToStringFun: (T forSome { type T }) => Unit = value => println(value)
```

you will notice that it's `Any`. BTW, using existential types via `forSome` is [being dropped](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html).

Functions are monomorphic in Scala, unlike methods that are polymorphic. Personally, I think [this](http://milessabin.com/blog/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/) article(s) provides a great explanation on that topic.

Answer (score 4):

Scala 3 (Dotty) should provide [polymorphic function types](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672), so akin to polymorphic method

```
scala> def myToString[A](value: A) = println(value)
def myToString[A](value: A): Unit
```

we could write polymorphic function

```
scala> val myToString: [A] => A => Unit = [A] => (value: A) => println(value)
val myToString: PolyFunction{apply: [A](x$1: A): Unit} = <function1>
```

which is equivalent to [`PolyFunction`](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/ca216a851037369fd83fd1bc31f3331a1a84424d/library/src/scala/PolyFunction.scala) refined with polymorphic `apply` method

```
scala> val myToString: PolyFunction {def apply[A](value: A): Unit} = new PolyFunction {
     |   def apply[A](value: A): Unit = println(value)
     | }
val myToString: PolyFunction{apply: [A](value: A): Unit} = <function1>
```

Mind to not confuse polymorphic function type

```
[A] => B
```

with type lambda which is on a different "level"

```
[A] =>> B
```

where the second `>` in arrow `=>>` [lifts](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672#issuecomment-495184279) to a type-level.

Note this feature is still being worked on as per [documentation is missing polymorphic functions #7594](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/7594)

Answer (score 3):

`(T forSome { type T })` is just `Any`, so `(T forSome { type T }) => Unit` is `Any => Unit`, which is a **subtype** of arbitrary `A => Unit`.

Generally `F[T] forSome { type T }` is not `F[Any]` (it's so for covariant `F` i.e. `F[+X]`). `F[T] forSome {type T}` aka `F[_]` is a **supertype** of all types `F[A]` (including `F[Any]`). Actually, it's the minimal such supertype i.e. the least upper bound of all types `F[A]` (for fixed `F` and arbitrary `A`).

> It seems however that
>
> ```
> val mySeqToString: (Seq[T] forSome {type T}) => String = {
>   case head +: tail => s"$head +: " + seqToString(tail)
>   case Nil => "Nil" 
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> def seqToString[T](seq: Seq[T]): String = seq match {
>   case head +: tail => s"$head +: " + seqToString(tail)
>   case Nil => "Nil" 
> }
> ```
>
> correct ?

No.

`def seqToString[T](seq: Seq[T]): String` is universal [quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic))

```
seqToString: (∀ T) => (seq: Seq[T]) => String
```

while `val mySeqToString: (Seq[T] forSome {type T}) => String` is existential quantification

```
seqToString: ((∃ T), (seq: Seq[T])) => String
```

In the first case you can specify `T` and your code will work for this specific `T`, e.g. `seqToString[Int]` will accept `Seq[Int]`, `seqToString[String]` will accept `Seq[String]` etc.

In the second case you do not control `T`, the method accepts all `Seq[Int]`, `Seq[String]` etc.

Since `Seq` is covariant, `Seq[T] forSome { type T }` is just `Seq[Any]`.

In a dependently typed language existential quantification [leads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#Formal_definition) to Sigma-types, universal quantification leads to Pi-types.

Comment: So this would be a generic function however `val mySeqToString: (Seq[T] forSome {type T}) => String = {
 case head +: tail => s"$head +: " + seqToString(tail)
 case Nil => "Nil"
}` ??

Comment: Edited my question to add the second case which reflect your answer.

Comment: But overall i will just stick to method to write things that are generic i guess :)

Comment: thank you so much for expanding on that. Will have to come back to that question after some readying :)

Comment: @MaatDeamon yeah I was about to comment that your second example is not really that different from the first one. I can come with an example that at first looks like it worked like a generic: `val genericFun: ((T, List[T]) forSome {type T}) => Boolean = { case (t, list) => list.contains(t) }` and a quick test seems to indicate this worked: `genericFun(3 -> List(1, 3, 5))` however, we can see that at the end it is just **Any** again with this test: `genericFun(3 -> List(1, 0, ""))` also, the main problem is that we can not reuse that `T` on other arguments or in the return type.